# Most idiomatic way to create a fix-length array from a function

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization, immutability

While implementing an octree, the childs of a node are represented using a 8-elements array of boxes.

I would like to create this array and populate it with a recursive function.

Here is the (ugly) code I ended up using:

```rust
{
    let mut temp = [Box::new(Foo::default()); 8];

    for i in 0..8 {
        temp[i] = Box::new(my_foo_generator(i));
    }
    temp
}
```

But it requires `Foo` to implement `Default` even if it does not make sense in this context: if I have a function that create a `Foo` from an index, I don't need to initialize the array before populating it.

Another important point is that I want this code to be scalable: If the array I want to create have 50000 elements, I'm not sure a macro is the right way to go.

In a more general way, my question would be: can I create an array from a function that takes the index of the element, without using mutability ?

#### EDIT:

I discovered that it exists the [array_init](https://crates.io/crates/array-init) crate. You can use it like this:

```rust
use array_init::array_init;

{
   let result : [Box<Foo>; 8] 
              = array_init(|i| Box::new(my_foo_generator(i)))
}
```